# Does the but in this sentence make it a simple sentence or a complex sentence?

Tags: types-of-sentences

I was given the sentence "I am but a man" and I was wondering if this sentence is a complex sentence or a simple sentence.

Comment: Hello Reina.  When you have a moment, please take our [tour] and review our [help] to learn more about how this site works.  Could you [edit] your question to explain where you're getting the definitions (or what the definitions you're using are) for simple and complex sentences?

Answer (score 1):

It is **not a complex sentence.** A complex or compound sentence must contain more than one clause.  Each clause has a verb in some form. There is only one verb and only one clause in your example. The word "but" is not acting as a conjunction to link clauses. It acts as an adverb, meaning "only".

Comment: A well drafted answer with a strong reasoning [UPVOTED]